# How to get output of today() function as string in google sheet

Tags: spreadsheet, google-docs

I want to append quote to the date value which i receive from `=today()-1` function.

Expected output is eg. - "30/05/2018"

Comment: why a negative comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could Achieve with below -

```
=CONCATENATE(CHAR(34),TO_TEXT(today()),CHAR(34))
```

Comment: why a negative comment?